# PDFBox text extraction, rotation and font name, size

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am using the latest PDFBOX library to extract the text, in order to do this, I wrote my custom PDFStreamEngine (shwoing part of the code, but the rest should be similar):

```
else if ("Tf".equals(operation) && parsingTextObject) {
            if (operands.size() < 2) {
                throw new MissingOperandException(operator, operands);
            }

            COSBase base0 = operands.get(0);
            COSBase base1 = operands.get(1);
            if (!(base0 instanceof COSName)) {
                return;
            }
            if (!(base1 instanceof COSNumber)) {
                return;
            }
            COSName fontName = (COSName) base0;
            float fontSize = ((COSNumber) base1).floatValue();
            getGraphicsState().getTextState().setFontSize(fontSize);
            PDFont font = getResources().getFont(fontName);
            getGraphicsState().getTextState().setFont(font);
}
```

However, I am having 3 problems:
first one: "Tf" Operator - in PDF  /F1 1 Tf : when I display fontName and size,  it shows: EVMANJ+MyriadPro-Regular, size 1; however, the actual font name on illustrator and adobe acrobat: Myriad Pro, size 8 pt

Second issue: the text is vertical as shown, How to extract rotation for the text?
[image]

Third issue: How to properly deal with TJ operator?

P.S: I can provide the pdf in private.

Comment: 1) This is a subset, and size 1 means that Adobe used a scale instead of using the 8 directly in the Tf command; 2) current transformation matrix / text matrix 3) I don't understand the question - maybe have a look at the PDF 32000 specification? Also have a look at the PrintTextLocations example in the source code download, and at the TextPosition object. Also look at your file with PDFDebugger and then the content stream.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thanks a lot,PrintTextLocations is very good example, however, I am already extending PDFStreamEngine and I need to stick with it, is there a method I can override which perform similar functionality to writeString ?

Comment: I can't answer that because I don't know enough of your code and I've never extended PDFStreamEngine (except maybe in copy & paste code). However that example I mentioned extends PDFTextStripper, which extends LegacyPDFStreamEngine. which extends PDFStreamEngine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for this question is not direct, I had to extend showFontGlyph

```
protected void showFontGlyph(Matrix textRenderingMatrix, PDFont font, int code, String unicode, Vector displacement) throws IOException {
..do you logic here}
```

And in order to find the rotation, I had to copy paste the code from PDFBox 1.8 into my class

```
/**
 * Return the direction/orientation of the string in this object based on
 * its text matrix.
 * 
 * @return The direction of the text (0, 90, 180, or 270)
 */
public int getDir() {
    int direction = -1;
    if (direction < 0) {
        float a = getTextMatrix().getScaleY();
        float b = getTextMatrix().getShearY();
        float c = getTextMatrix().getShearX();
        float d = getTextMatrix().getScaleX();
        // 12 0 left to right
        // 0 12
        if (a > 0 && Math.abs(b) < d && Math.abs(c) < a && d > 0) {
            direction = 0;
        }
        // -12 0 right to left (upside down)
        // 0 -12
        else if (a < 0 && Math.abs(b) < Math.abs(d) && Math.abs(c) < Math.abs(a) && d < 0) {
            direction = 180;
        }
        // 0 12 up
        // -12 0
        else if (Math.abs(a) < Math.abs(c) && b > 0 && c < 0 && Math.abs(d) < b) {
            direction = 90;
        }
        // 0 -12 down
        // 12 0
        else if (Math.abs(a) < c && b < 0 && c > 0 && Math.abs(d) < Math.abs(b)) {
            direction = 270;
        } else {
            direction = 0;
        }
    }
    return direction;
}
```

And I call getDir function when I detect TJ operator when processing the stream.

Comment: Your `getDir` only returns multiples of 90° but text can be drawn at arbitrary angles.

Comment: @mkl that is right, fortunately, the case I am working on only has 4 angle degrees: 0, 90, 180, 270. This is the only working solution I found using PDFBox 2.0.x