# How to get the text rotation angle with PDFBOX

Tags: fonts, rotation, pdfbox, text-extraction

I have a job to remove a watermark in a PDF. I find some text watermark show in PDF with some angle. So I can judge whether the text is a possible watermark or not by the angle of text. Now I have a problem to get the rotation angle of text.

I have tried to call `TextPositon.getRation()`, `TextPositon.getDir()`, I also referenced [Rotate text in pdfbox with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054396/rotate-text-in-pdfbox-with-java).

mkl said "Your getDir only returns multiples of 90° but text can be drawn at arbitrary angles" from [PDFBox text extraction, rotation and font name, size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589478/pdfbox-text-extraction-rotation-and-font-name-size),
but I still feel confused.

Comment: @mkl <a href="https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/RotatedTextOnLine.java#L34" rel="nofollow noreferrer">RotatedTextOnLine</a> only have how to create text with rotation angle. Now i want to get the ratation angle.

Comment: Tilman in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66562440/1729265) shows how to retrieve the angle from `TextPosition.getTextMatrix()`. The only remaining question is whether the text you look for actually can easily be found...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the ExtractText tool:

```
static int getAngle(TextPosition text)
{
    Matrix m = text.getTextMatrix().clone();
    m.concatenate(text.getFont().getFontMatrix());
    return (int) Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(m.getShearY(), m.getScaleY())));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. getAngle() retrun the correct angle value.